# How to use BASH Curl and $_GET URL with Multiple Variable Parameters?

Tags: bash, curl, scripting, get

(I updated the question to make it easier to understand)

This works:

```
curl 'domain.com/script.php?COMPUTER=I7&LOGTIME=12:13:14&CPUTEMP=68.0C&CPUUSAGE=100%'
```

The problem is the parameter values are stored in variables. So far everything I have tried will not work, including the following:

```
curl "domain.com/script.php?COMPUTER=I7&LOGTIME=${TTIME}&CPUTEMP=${TTEMP}&CPUUSAGE=${UUSAGE}"
```

and

```
curl 'domain.com/script.php?COMPUTER=I7&LOGTIME=${TTIME}&CPUTEMP=${TTEMP}&CPUUSAGE=${UUSAGE}'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

--

I just ran curl with the -v flag, this is what I got back:

```
* Trying <IP ADDRESS REMOVED>...

* TCP_NODELAY set

* Connected to <HOST REMOVED> (<IP ADDRESS REMOVED> port 80 (#0)

> GET /writebhosts.php?COMPUTER=I7&LOGTIME=17:48:39&CPUTEMP=70.0°C&CPUUSAGE=100% HTTP/1.1

> Host: <HOST>

> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0

> Accept: */*
```

I have removed my IP Address and Host domain for security reasons.

--

I just re-ran the static value code, and its the ° symbol which seems to be causing the issue, when trying to store the GET data into the CSV file. This was missing initially from the static values code which is why 'it worked'.

Its a simple fix as the ° symbol was hard coded into the bash script.

**Thanks to everyone that pointed me in the right direction.**

Comment: What error do you get in your second example with double quotes?

Comment: I just get an error (in Terminal) from the code in the end file trying to read the data and store it into a CSV file. <html><body><h1>400 Bad Request</h1> Your browser sent an invalid request</body></html> The end page is just php to read the GET data and store it into the CSV, with no html output.

Comment: it could be the `CPUTEMP` parameter the value you are sending in the second example is `70.0°C` but in the working example it's `68.0c`. do the degree symbol `°` and the case `c vs C` make a difference?

Comment: Please note that in the first example you have `CPUTEMP=68.0` and in the second `&CPUTEMP=70.0°C`. Degree sign `°` causes the error.

Comment: I just re-ran the static value code, and its the ° symbol which seems to be causing the issue, when trying to store the GET data into the CSV file.